# Need Help Building List to Maximize Overall Output

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list of items in my database, with a name and corresponding output.
I have to then sort the list and maximize the output in various containers.

So I have a list like:

```
List1     100
List2     120
List3     125
List4     101
List5     100
List6     106
List7     110
 ...
List150   110
```

I have 3 containers that have 4 slots each.  I need to maximize the output in each containers, and keep them fairly close together as far as max output.
So I can't take the top 4 and put it in the first container, otherwise it will be full long before the last container is, and will cause problems.  I need them to fill at approx the same rate.

The result would be something like

```
Container 1
List3  125
List8  118
List27 111
List7  110

Container 2
List2  120
List33 120
List18 115
List42 110

Container 3
List14 120
List61 118
List52 119
List99 108
```

I am trying to figure out how to attack this problem and I'm stuck.

The process I have so far is:
Sort list from largest to smallest
Take the number of spaces I nee to fill from the top (containers * slots)
Add the numbers, and average.  That will give me my target, or at least a place to start.
I don't know how to go about actually filling the spots and shifting things around.  I can do it manually of course, but no idea how to implement it programmatically.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: While this is an interesting question, it might be a bit too broad for SO? Have you considered running a query that is sorted by deviation of the list number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the list items like before and just fill each container round robin style giving each container the top item in the list one at a time until they are full.

This assumes though that maximizing output is the first priority and then keeping them as close to the same as possible second to that. If you have a certain requirement of how close the outpus of each container must be to each other then it becomes more complicated.

Comment: Why the down vote? I thought at first this might be the knapsack problem but it is definitely not as the poster says there are exactly 4 slots per container.

Comment: I voted you up to even it out.  I did that on a few, and I had one set where the top number was like 256 and the next highest was 130, so that container was skewed quite a bit.  Ideally I like to keep the containers +/-5 of the average, but I had one set where a container was 50 more than the rest, and they were all about 10 under the average.  Wasn't ideal, but it was the best that could be done with that set.

Comment: Ok, that changes the problem. You might want to update your question to clarify that.

Comment: Also, given a threshold for maximum deviation this may or not be possible depending on the values. For example if you have one value of a million and rest were all less then 10 there would be no way to keep an average within 5% (unless you want to preserve deviation at all costs and then maximize output then it becomes a different problem again)